# Show more items in react state when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to create a component that show some of the state but show more once a button is clicked. Each time a button is clicked it should show 3 more items.

I tried a few different things, here is my current code: Any help and explanation is appreciated:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
class ShowSomeItems extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
      this.state = {
      cars: [
        { "name": "Audi", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "BMW", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Chevrolet", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Citroen", "country": "France" },
        { "name": "Hyundai", "country": "South Korea" },
        { "name": "Mercedes-Benz", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Renault", "country": "France" },
        { "name": "Seat", "country": "Spain" },
        { "name": "Dodge", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "BMW", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Tesla", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Volkswagen", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Hyundai", "country": "South Korea" },
        { "name": "Jaguar", "country": "United Kingdom" },
        { "name": "GMC", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Bentley", "country": "United Kingdom" },
      ],
      numberOfitemsShown: 5,
    }
}


showMore = () => {
    let numberToincrementBy = 3;
    if(this.state.numberOfitemsShown < this.state.car.length){
     itemsToShow = this.cars.slice(0, incremenrIndex)
      numberToincrementBy+3
      return itemsToShow
    }
  }

render() {

    let itemsToShow = "Loading...";  
       if(this.state.numberOfitemsShown){
         itemsToShow =  for(let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        <li key={x}>{this.state.cars[x]['name']}</li>
       }
  }

return (
      <div>
        <ul>
         {itemsToShow}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.showMore}>
          show more
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<ShowSomeItems />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach in this case is to take advantage of component state to keep the current number of items you want to show and increment it with the button. It's cleaner and it goes well with the react way of defining UI. Example:

```
class ShowSomeItems extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      cars: [
        { "name": "Audi", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "BMW", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Chevrolet", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Citroen", "country": "France" },
        { "name": "Hyundai", "country": "South Korea" },
        { "name": "Mercedes-Benz", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Renault", "country": "France" },
        { "name": "Seat", "country": "Spain" },
        { "name": "Dodge", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "BMW", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Tesla", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Volkswagen", "country": "Germany" },
        { "name": "Hyundai", "country": "South Korea" },
        { "name": "Jaguar", "country": "United Kingdom" },
        { "name": "GMC", "country": "USA" },
        { "name": "Bentley", "country": "United Kingdom" },
      ],
      numberOfitemsShown: 5,
    }
  }


  showMore = () => {
    if (this.state.numberOfitemsShown + 3 <= this.state.cars.length) {
      this.setState(state => ({ numberOfitemsShown: state.numberOfitemsShown + 3 }));
    } else {
      this.setState({ numberOfitemsShown: this.state.cars.length })
    }
  }

  render() {

    const itemsToShow = this.state.cars
      .slice(0, this.state.numberOfitemsShown)
      .map(car => <li key={car.name}>{car.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {itemsToShow.length ? itemsToShow : "Loading..."}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.showMore}>
          show more
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can make the render method cleaner extracting `itemsToShow` into a component like this:

```
const Items = props => {
  if (props.cars.length === 0) {
    return "Loading..."
  }
  return props.cars
    .slice(0, props.numberOfitemsShown)
    .map(car => <li key={car.name}>{car.name}</li>)
}

class ShowSomeItems extends React.Component {
//rest excluded for brevity

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <Items cars={this.state.cars} numberOfitemsShown={this.state.numberOfitemsShown} />
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.showMore}>
          show more
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow this makes much more sense. Just wondering how would this work if the itemsToShow was a functional component instead of a variable ?

Comment: @bruce I edited the answer to show an alternative with a component that takes the cars and the number to show as a prop. I hope this clears that up

Answer (score 1):

Those who require the functional component version, can check this. I have changed the class based component which @SrThompson written into a functional

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const carsList = [
  { name: "Audi", country: "Germany" },
  { name: "BMW", country: "Germany" },
  { name: "Chevrolet", country: "USA" },
  { name: "Citroen", country: "France" },
  { name: "Hyundai", country: "South Korea" },
  { name: "Mercedes-Benz", country: "Germany" },
  { name: "Renault", country: "France" },
  { name: "Seat", country: "Spain" },
  { name: "Dodge", country: "USA" },
  { name: "BMW", country: "Germany" },
  { name: "Tesla", country: "USA" },
  { name: "Volkswagen", country: "Germany" },
  { name: "Hyundai", country: "South Korea" },
  { name: "Jaguar", country: "United Kingdom" },
  { name: "GMC", country: "USA" },
  { name: "Bentley", country: "United Kingdom" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [cars] = useState(carsList);
  const [numberOfitemsShown, setNumberOfItemsToShown] = useState(5);

  const showMore = () => {
    if (numberOfitemsShown + 3 <= cars.length) {
      setNumberOfItemsToShown(numberOfitemsShown + 3);
    } else {
      setNumberOfItemsToShown(cars.length);
    }
  };

  const itemsToShow = useMemo(() => {
    return cars
      .slice(0, numberOfitemsShown)
      .map((car, index) => <li key={car.name + index}>{car.name}</li>);
  }, [cars, numberOfitemsShown]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{itemsToShow.length ? itemsToShow : "Loading..."}</ul>
      <button onClick={showMore}>show more</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-microservice-czpu0)